# Using R to Shift timestamp data to account for end of daylight savings time

Tags: r, lubridate

I set out some trail cameras before the end of daylight savings, so a subset of my data has timestamps that are off by 1 hour.

For an example of my raw data, site 0057 and site 0156 were placed before the time change so any records after 11/7/21 02:00 need to be shifted one hour back.

Site 0419 was set after the time change so those timestamps are already correct and don't need to be shifted.

```
    Station    DateTimeOriginal       Date     Time
1  Site 0057 2021-11-01 00:04:25 2021-11-01  0:04:25
2  Site 0057 2021-11-06 23:57:47 2021-11-06 23:57:47
3  Site 0057 2021-11-07 01:33:50 2021-11-07  1:33:50
4  Site 0057 2021-11-07 02:11:04 2021-11-07  2:11:04
5  Site 0057 2021-11-10 23:38:54 2021-11-10 23:38:54
6  Site 0057 2021-11-11 00:41:57 2021-11-11  0:41:57
7  Site 0156 2021-11-04 13:18:56 2021-11-04 13:18:56
8  Site 0156 2021-11-05 02:41:01 2021-11-05  2:41:01
9  Site 0156 2021-11-15 06:50:12 2021-11-15  6:50:12
10 Site 0419 2021-11-08 15:57:59 2021-11-08 15:57:59
11 Site 0419 2021-11-13 07:35:42 2021-11-13  7:35:42
12 Site 0419 2021-11-14 00:17:15 2021-11-14  0:17:15
```

My actual dataset has around 2000 records from 100 stations that need to be changed. I'm new with R, and dates/times are very tricky for me so any help is much appreciated.

dput() table:

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(
      Station = c(
        "Site 0057",
        "Site 0057",
        "Site 0057",
        "Site 0057",
        "Site 0057",
        "Site 0057",
        "Site 0156",
        "Site 0156",
        "Site 0156",
        "Site 0419",
        "Site 0419",
        "Site 0419"
      ),
      DateTimeOriginal = c(
        "2021-11-01 00:04:25",
        "2021-11-06 23:57:47",
        "2021-11-07 01:33:50",
        "2021-11-07 02:11:04",
        "2021-11-10 23:38:54",
        "2021-11-11 00:41:57",
        "2021-11-04 13:18:56",
        "2021-11-05 02:41:01",
        "2021-11-15 06:50:12",
        "2021-11-08 15:57:59",
        "2021-11-13 07:35:42",
        "2021-11-14 00:17:15"
      ),
      Date = c(
        "2021-11-01",
        "2021-11-06",
        "2021-11-07",
        "2021-11-07",
        "2021-11-10",
        "2021-11-11",
        "2021-11-04",
        "2021-11-05",
        "2021-11-15",
        "2021-11-08",
        "2021-11-13",
        "2021-11-14"
      ),
      Time = c(
        "0:04:25",
        "23:57:47",
        "1:33:50",
        "2:11:04",
        "23:38:54",
        "0:41:57",
        "13:18:56",
        "2:41:01",
        "6:50:12",
        "15:57:59",
        "7:35:42",
        "0:17:15"
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-12L)
  )
```

Comment: Can you share your table using `dput`?

Comment: I added the dput to the original question. is that what you were looking for? (still new to all of this)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be adding an hour to dates after "2021-11-07 00:01:00". Since once the clock hits 2am those times are shifted back 1 hour. You need to set your timezone here, I chose "America/New_York" as a default.

Edit: I modified my original answer as I now see that Site 0419 does not need to be updated and I updated the columns in place instead of creating new ones.

For the sites that need updating you can create a vector and then collapse them with "|" for the condition.

```
sites_to_update = c("0057", "0156")
cond = paste0(sites_to_update, collapse = "|")
# insert 'cond' after the %like% statement below
```

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df = as.data.table(df1)
tz =  "America/New_York"

# Convert to datetime object 
df[, DateTimeOriginal := as_datetime(DateTimeOriginal, tz = tz)]

# Subset to only 0057 and 0156 and update if not on dst time
df[Station %like% c("0057|0156"),
   DateTimeOriginal := fifelse(!dst(DateTimeOriginal), DateTimeOriginal + hours(1), DateTimeOriginal)
  ]

# Update Date and Time columns
df[, `:=` (Date = date(DateTimeOriginal),
           Time = format(DateTimeOriginal, format = "%H:%M:%S"))]
```

```
      Station    DateTimeOriginal       Date     Time
 1: Site 0057 2021-11-01 00:04:25 2021-11-01 00:04:25
 2: Site 0057 2021-11-06 23:57:47 2021-11-06 23:57:47
 3: Site 0057 2021-11-07 02:33:50 2021-11-07 02:33:50
 4: Site 0057 2021-11-07 03:11:04 2021-11-07 03:11:04
 5: Site 0057 2021-11-11 00:38:54 2021-11-11 00:38:54
 6: Site 0057 2021-11-11 01:41:57 2021-11-11 01:41:57
 7: Site 0156 2021-11-04 13:18:56 2021-11-04 13:18:56
 8: Site 0156 2021-11-05 02:41:01 2021-11-05 02:41:01
 9: Site 0156 2021-11-15 07:50:12 2021-11-15 07:50:12
10: Site 0419 2021-11-08 15:57:59 2021-11-08 15:57:59
11: Site 0419 2021-11-13 07:35:42 2021-11-13 07:35:42
12: Site 0419 2021-11-14 00:17:15 2021-11-14 00:17:15
```